Using Visual Studio Code editor with AWS CLI?
I a pretty new to using Visual Studio Code and also somewhat new to using the AWS CLI and APIs.  I have installed the AWS CLI, configured profiles, etc. and installed VS Code along with the AWS Toolkit.  So far, I have been really successful in working with the Amazon APIs via the AWS CLI using the Cygwin (64) Terminal.  However, I'm used to programming in other environments and IDEs in such a way that I develop code in an IDE editor, ideally with rich IDE features such as IntelliSense, syntax highlighting, code completion, type-aheads, etc. and then I can submit highlighted code to be executed.  For example, I am a statistician and we work a lot in R and RStudio, where the IDE there allows me to develop code quickly and efficiently in the editor because as I type out function names, suggested arguments appear on-screen as part of the integrated code completion functionality.  When I'm done with a block of code or when I reach the end of the line of some code I want to run in RStudio, I simply press Shift+Enter and the highlighted code block (or single line of code where the cursor is placed if code isn't highlighted) is sent to the terminal and executed.
I want to basically do this in Visual Studio Code with the the AWS CLI to work with the AWS QuickSight API, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with Visual Studio Code, even after watching numerous videos and Googling for solutions.  Can anyone offer any advice and explain how I might go about setting up in Windows Visual Studio Code so that works with and is fully integrated with the AWS CLI and APIs?
I will say that I have had some limited luck in getting Visual Studio to work with the CLI, but I suspect I don't have this set up quite right since I don't get code completion, syntax highlighting, and other rich editor features with how I've got things currently "sort of" working.  Here's what I did in this case:

I installed Visual Studio Code along with the AWS Tookit Extension (but with this approach, I don't think I'm even using the AWS Toolkit features -- see below).
I can open a text editor in VS Code by clicking File->New Text file.
I can authenticate into the AWS CLI by typing into the text file:  aws sso login --profile prod-env and then pressing Ctrl+Shift+P to activate the VS Code Command Palette and selecting "Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal."  This then allows me to authenticate and from there I can run other CLI commands as needed.

I'm sure I can probably next map a keyboard shortcut for Shift+Enter to the "Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal" command which gets me close to what I need.  The problem, now, however, is that I'm still not able to see code completions or syntax highlighting for the AWS APIs.  Does anyone know how I can get this working so the editor is fully integrated with the API complete with IntelliSense, code completions, syntax highlighting, and the ability for me to send the code to AWS for execution?

So I don't think this is entirely possible since the CLI is meant to be a command line tool, so you don't get full rich text editors typically for these types of tools.  However, I was able to get something working that comes VERY close to what I was hoping for, only it doesn't support syntax highlighting (but I suppose if I spent some time, I could create my own syntax highlighting).  I do get useful code completion and can execute a single line or block of commands from the Visual Studio editor as I was hoping.  So, to se this up, I carried out these steps:

Install Visual Studio Code if not already installed.
Launch VS Code and open a text editor (File->New Text File)
Place the cursor in the text editor window and press Ctrl+Shift+P.
Enter “Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal” and then click the gear icon that appears to the right of it when it shows up in the list.  A keyboard binding window will now appear.
Right click the first line of the keyboard binding next to the words “Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal” and click “Add Keybinding” from the pop-up menu.
A new pop-up menu will appear that displays “Press desired key combination and then press Enter.”  Press Ctrl+Enter and then press Enter again to create the key binding.
Right click the first line again and select “Change when expression.”
Type in “editorTextFocus” followed by enter.  Your keyboard binding should look like the one below:
Close or X-out of the keyboard binding mapping.

This should now map the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Enter to the text editor window.  Now, whenever you highlight a block of code in the editor you can send it to the Terminal and have it immediately executed by simply pressing Ctrl+Enter.  Alternatively, if no code is selected in the editor and you press Ctrl+Enter, the complete content of the single line that your cursor is on in the editor window will be sent to the Terminal and executed.  You can verify that this is working by attempting to authenticate now through the editor:

Open a new blank text file window or use the one that’s already open, but just make sure no other text is in it.
On the first line enter aws sso login –profile <profile name from your .aws config file> and then press Ctrl+Enter.

Your authentication code should be sent to the Terminal and immediately executed.  Your default browser should then launch and ask you to verify authentication via SSO.  Click the acceptance.
Now, any code you enter into the editor will be executed against the AWS CLI by simply pressing Ctrl+Enter!  When I start editing code, I also get suggested code completion text popping up in the editor and if I press the Tab key, the suggested code is inserted into the editor.
This has saved me a ton of time and hope it helps others.
